# How to iterate an action across all files in a directory, and then store the results in a different file using Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sentiment-analysis

I have a total of 100 .db files stored on my Google Drive. All rows in these files contain a text column, for which I need to calculate the Sentiment Polarity Scores for each row, using vaderSentiment package.

I have managed to do so for one of these .db files, but I want to repeat this calculation for all 99 other files in the directory. Additionally, I want to store the mean of this '[sentiment_ compound_polarity']' column of every file in my Google Drive directory in a .csv file. This file should have just two columns with 100 rows (1 for each file), containing the file name and df['sentiment_compound_polarity'].mean() for every single .db file stored in '/content/drive/My Drive/Database Files/'.

I've managed to get some code to work, which prints the average sentiment scores for each file but I don't know how to store it in a .csv (of course I can just copy/paste it, but I want to know how to do it).

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

drive.mount('/content/drive')

gdrive = '/content/drive/My Drive/Database Files/'

for db in os.listdir(gdrive):
  with sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(gdrive, db)) as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(SELECT * FROM table, conn)
    df['sentiment_compound_polarity'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: SentimentIntensityAnalyzer().polarity_scores(x)['compound'])
    print (df['sentiment_compound_polarity'].mean())
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You have listed a lot of distinct steps. First you need to figure out which one is the problem, so you can ask a question focused on that.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Based on your latest edit, the next step is to search for documentation with these keywords: "pandas write csv"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to prepare a new dataframe (outside the for loop):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['db','mean'])
```

Then in the loop add a new row with the db name and mean:

```
df = df.append(dict(zip(df.columns,[db, df['sentiment_compound_polarity'].mean()])), ignore_index=True)
```

Then at the end of the code, save the dataframe to CSV file:

```
df.to_csv('means.csv')
```